# QNap - MySQL accesingdatabase from remote site

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm playing with MySQL and C#.NET and would like to test an application that allows me to query data from my database from a remote site. 
I have MySQL set up on my QNAP and have phpMyAdmin installed. All working fine.

I have created a simple application that connects to the MySQL on the QNAP and returns a query. This works fine from my desktop. When I change the IP to my external IP, I cannot get the application to connect.

I have forwarded the ports on my router (confirmed with a port scan), I have tried adding/removing a "bind-address=0.0.0.0" as well as ensured that "skip-networking" is commented out. I have also added a "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;"

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what else I can look at, or where I can look in the QNAP to see if the connections are coming in and being rejected? Unfortunately my Router doesn't have a connection log.

Thanks

Comment: What does this mean? **When I change the IP to my external IP**. What IP are you changing? The IP upon which MySQL is accepting connections? The IP from which you are requesting connections?

Comment: Apologies, what I mean is that within my application I have a text field that I put in the IP address of the MySQL server (my QNAP). Locally i use the IP 192.168.20.254 and then when I try this remotely I use my external IP address (e.g. 119.140.xxx.xxx).